# after three characters all letter change with asterisk

Tags: asp-classic, response.write

making a preview form with asp classic for customers. 
I have data "email field" in db.for example , there is an email address in email_field.

> JohnDoe@mail.com

but I want to customers see ;

> Joh**********

I could not solve this problem. Which code can I use for this ?

```
<%=Response.Write email_field %>
<%=Left(rs_mydb("email_field"),3)%>
<%=Replace(rs_mydb("email_field")),"","*"%>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use replace. Instead, you can build a new string to print.

```vb
<%
emailFromDb = rs_mydb("email_field")
emailForPrint = Left(emailFromDb, 3) & String(Len(emailFromDb) - 3, "*")
Response.Write emailForPrint
%>
```

Comment: Worth adding some sanity check, so that the code won't crash when there is no email, or email shorter than three letters. (data might not be validated before being put in database, so maybe even XSS protection)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It would, but I strategically choose to not do it. It's often not worth it. It does not seem right to me to spend more time than the OPs anymore. I expect them to show more interest than me to their own questions at least. When it happens (a feedback for example) a conversation happens, therefore and update for more reliable suggestions is definitely made. BTW Hi, I have not seen you around here ([asp-classic], [vbscript]) for a long time :)

Comment: Well, agree about more complex things, but simple If..Then to validate length is pretty trivial. I'm only following subscription emails these days, most of the times the questions are already answered, like this one. :-)